# How to left align the element when using begin align, not the whole equation?

Tags: align

I am using begin align command and want to left align my equation. I learned that using `flalign` I can left align the whole equation. But this is not what I need now. I want to left align my equation "componentwisely". The following is what I have typed. and the right hand sides are automatically right-aligned. How can I fix this?

```
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v^j}&=&\frac{\partial f}{\partial u^l}\frac{\partial u^l}{\partial v^j}\\
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial v^j\partial v^i}&=&\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^l\partial u^m}\frac{\partial u^m}{\partial v^i}\frac{\partial u^l}{\partial v^j}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial u^l}\frac{\partial^2u^l}{\partial v^j\partial v^i}
\end{align*}
```

Pictorial description.
I want to change 1 to appear like 2.

```
1.(right aligned right hand side)
_________________________
aa= aaaaaaaaaaa

aa=        aaaa
_________________________
2.(left aligned right hand side)
_________________________
aa= aaaaaaaaaaa

aa= aaaa
```

---

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the second `&` in

```
&=&
```

so that it becomes

```
&=
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v^j} &=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u^l}\frac{\partial u^l}{\partial v^j}\\
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial v^j\partial v^i} &=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^l\partial u^m}\frac{\partial u^m}{\partial v^i}\frac{\partial u^l}{\partial v^j}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial u^l}\frac{\partial^2u^l}{\partial v^j\partial v^i}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Always remember that `&` (the alignment specifier inside `align` and friends) has right and left alignment pairs i.e., left hand side of `&` is right aligned and right hand side is left aligned in pairs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and comment! But why would the second ampersand mark make the right hand side of my equation right aligned if it "left-aligns" everything on its right side?

Comment: @texlearner23 - `&=&` is syntax from the badly-deprecated `eqnarray` environment. In environments such as `align`, it is possible to have multiple blocks, each with their own alignment point specified by an `&`. However, that's not what you're after here, right? For more information on aligning single and multiple blocks of equations using the tools of the `amsmath` package, see section 3 of that package's [user guide](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf).

Comment: @texlearner23 `right align & left align` makes one pair. Another `&` will start another `right left ` pair. So `right align & left align & right align` is what is happening in your case.